# In-app Billing Поэтапно

Tags: java, android

Как подключить встроенную покупку в приложении? Если быть точнее, pro версию, так сказать ключ.
Пользователь оплатил, и открываются дополнительные функции в приложении.

Хотелось бы, чтобы расписали все подробно и поэтапно. Как, куда, чего?

Answer (score 3):

Так как конкретного вопроса нету а работа In-app billing описана в документации - могу посоветовать вам пример кода от Google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

Ну и коротко:

1. Вам нужно подключить In-app billing service в своем приложении https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html
2. Залить альфа/бета версию своего приложения в PlayStore
3. Создать для своего приложения товар или подписку
4. Написать реализацию или взять с примера который я указал выше и тестить)

Comment: Можно с вами пообщаться?Вы есть в вк?

Comment: Можно,  можете писать в Skype: kir_ya-ua или на Facebook: Kirill Stoianov, как будет свободное время я отвечу

Comment: Но я вам все равно настоятельно рекомендую прочитать еще и документацию по этому вопросу, а еще лучше пару раз прочитайте от и до